# Why am I getting fatal error of index out of range when using table view delegate?

Tags: swift, delegates, label, tableview, cell

I have two view controllers that both contain table views and I want it to where once a row is selected on the first table view, when it segues to the next table view the cells text's corresponds with whatever row they chose in the first table view. Imagine like the settings app, once you select on row, in the next view controller you are always presented the SAME cell text options for that corresponds with what you chose on the previous table view. I'm using a dictionary's keys and values and matched their index in the did select at row but when I run the code at runtime I get an error that says index out of range, anyone know why this is happening?

code to first view controller where error is happening:

```
 import UIKit

var trainingDict = ["Ball Handling" : ["1 Ball Stationary Drills", "1 Ball Combo Moves", "2 Ball Stationary Drills", "2 Ball Combo Moves", "2 Ball Partner Drills", "Handle Hoop Drills", "Placeholder"], "Shooting" : ["Form Shooting", "Spot Shooting", "Off The Dribble Shots", "Pull Up Jumpshots", "Catch & Shoots", "Free Throws", "Partner Shooting"], "Defense" : ["5 Star Drill", "Full Court Def. Slides", "1 v 1 Closeouts", "Gauntlet Drill", "Tennis Ball Reaction Drill", "Lane Slides", "Place Holder"], "Advanced Drills" : ["D Man Series", "Iso Series", "Double Move Series", "Gauntlet Series", "John Wall Drill", "Floater Series", "PlaceHolder"], "Vertimax Drills" : ["One Foot Jumps", "Box Jumps", "Resitance Slides", "Resistance Jumps", "Resistance Ball Handling", "Vertimax Sprints", "Slam Drill"], "Full Workouts" : ["Workout A", "Workout B", "Workout C", "Workout D", "Workout E", "Workout F", "Workout G"], "BHB Products" : ["Handle Hoops", "Handle Cubes", "Strech Bands", "Advocare", "Placeholder", "Placeholder2", "Placeholder3"]]
var gradient : CAGradientLayer!
var myIndex = 0


class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {



@IBOutlet weak var tableView: TableView!

var trainingCategories = [String]()
var arrayForKey = Array(trainingDict.values)
var selectedKey = 0




public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{

    return trainingDict.count
}




public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "bell" , for: indexPath) as! ViewControllerTableViewCell

    //cell details
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

    //gradient details
    gradient = CAGradientLayer()
    gradient.frame = tableView.bounds
    gradient.colors = [UIColor.black.cgColor, UIColor.darkGray.cgColor, UIColor.black.cgColor]
    tableView.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, at: 0)
    gradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0)
    gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 1.0)

    //details what the text label of cell displays
    var trainingCategories = Array(trainingDict.keys)
    trainingCategories.sort { return $0 < $1}

    cell.textLabel?.text = trainingCategories[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.white


    print(trainingCategories.count)

    return cell
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue", sender: self)
    selectedKey = Int(trainingCategories[indexPath.row])!
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "segue" {
       if let secondTableView = segue.destination as? DrillsViewController {

        secondTableView.keyIndex = selectedKey

        secondTableView.arrayForKey2 = arrayForKey

                }
            }

        }




override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    var trainingCategories = Array(trainingDict.keys)
    trainingCategories.sort { return $0 < $1}
}
```

added code for second view controller:

```
  import UIKit



  class DrillsViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

var arrayForKey2 = [[String]]()
var keyIndex = Int()

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: DrillsTableView!

@IBOutlet weak var drillLabel: UILabel!


public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{

    return arrayForKey2.count
}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell" , for: indexPath) as! DrillsTableViewCell

    //clear background color needed in order to display gradient cell
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

    //gradient configuration
    gradient = CAGradientLayer()
    gradient.frame = tableView.bounds
    gradient.colors = [UIColor.black.cgColor, UIColor.darkGray.cgColor, UIColor.black.cgColor]
    tableView.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, at: 0)
    gradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0)
    gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 1.0)



    //attributes for watch/play button
    cell.playButton.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.yellow.cgColor
    cell.playButton.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 2, height: 2)
    cell.playButton.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.7
    cell.playButton.layer.shadowRadius = 1

    //details for cell label display

    cell.drillTitle.text = "\(arrayForKey2[keyIndex][indexPath.row])"


    return cell
}




override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self

       }
```

Comment: In which line of your code are you getting this exception?

Answer (score 1):

In the below line:

```
selectedKey = Int(trainingCategories[indexPath.row])!
```

You are accessing `indexPath.row` element of array `trainingCategories`.

First of all check whether `trainingCategories` contains that many elements.

Accessing an array for index more than the element it contains would give a runtime exception `"Array index out of bounds"`.

Comment: If any of the answers helped in resolving your issue, mark it as accepted so that it help others knowing the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

values are not being passed maybe because you are performing segue first

```
performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue", sender: self)
    selectedKey = Int(trainingCategories[indexPath.row])!
```

replace it like this

```
selectedKey = Int(trainingCategories[indexPath.row])!
performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue", sender: self)
```

please try and let me know If issue still exist

Comment: go for it, I appreciate it

Comment: I examined your code You are passing int value to SelectedKey . Are you trying to pass Selected index from tableView ?

Comment: Yes that way both controllers pull with same index

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151333/discussion-between-ios-geek-and-captain-code).